# How can I detect when the jQuery UI collision fliped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, position, collision

I make a table with popup appear when hover `<td>` using jQuery UI position.

HTML - the popup with arrows left/right absolute position.

```
<div id="compare-popup">
    <div id="arrow-left"></div>
    <div id="arrow-right"></div>
    <table cellspacing="0" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">January 4th</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12,086</td>
            <td>6,992</td>
            <td>7,277</td>
            <td>6,612</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

java script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td.popup').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#compare-popup').fadeIn();
        $('#compare-popup').position({
            my: 'left + 10 top',
            at: 'right + 10 top',
            of: $(this),
            collision: 'flip'
        });
    }, 
    function(){
        $('#compare-popup').fadeOut();
        $('#compare-popup').position({
            my: 'left + 10 top',
            at: 'right + 10 top',
            of: $(this),
            collision: 'flip'
        });
    })
});
```

Now the jquery UI detect the browser's edge and make it be flipped.
The popup have left and right arrows point to the origin cell.
Please tell me how can I detect when the popup's flipped so I can show/hide each side arrow.

please follow the link to better understanding my problem.
http://ninninny.com/question/

Thank you.

Comment: I found this [ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5937) told that it's implemented with the using function. see [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).  but I still don't know how to use it, please give me an advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do it, but to keep it simple you could just add an if statement looking at the offset of the popup. Something like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f2RLP/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.popup').hoverIntent(function () {
        $('#compare-popup').fadeIn();
        $('#compare-popup').position({
            my: 'left+10 top',
            at: 'right+10 top',
            of: $(this), // or $("#otherdiv)
            collision: 'flip'
        });
        if ($('#compare-popup').offset().left > $(this).offset().left) {  //Important bit
            $('#arrow-left').show();
            $('#arrow-right').hide();
        } else {
            $('#arrow-left').hide();
            $('#arrow-right').show();
        }
    },

    function () {
        $('#compare-popup').fadeOut();
        $('#compare-popup').position({
            my: 'left+10 top',
            at: 'right+10 top',
            of: $(this), // or $("#otherdiv)
            collision: 'flip'
        });
    });
});
```